# convertapi gives issue while converting docx to pdf in IOS device

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, convertapi

I am trying to convert docx file to pdf using convertapi. The language i am using is Python and also i am doing some jinja2 templating in docx file. Everything works well with Android and web app. But it give 500 Internal server error while using in IOS device.

```
convert_api_result = convertapi.convert('pdf',
                                                {'File': demo_file.name},
                                                from_format='docx')
```

Error:
raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)\nrequests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='v2.convertapi.com')

I don't know why is this happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the response body?  In most cases, it contains a detailed exception message.

Comment: @Tomas This is the only exception i am having.